# remove last two characters from each line

Tags: text-processing

I've got a file containing:

```
Georgia
Unix
Google
```

The desired output is:

```
Georg
Un
Goog
```

Comment: Bash isn't a text editor, btw.

Comment: Thank you. I know that, it's just a thing i needed for a script. I use bash alot at work since the software provided can't provide all the needs.

Answer (score 19):

```
sed 's/..$//' < input > output
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`shell Parameter Expansion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and using Substring removal `${parameter%word}`/Substring Expansion `${parameter:offset:length}` syntax.

```bsh
"${line%??}"    # strip the shortest suffix pattern match the word 
"${line::-2}"   # strip last 2 characters (`bash 4.2` and above)
"${line: : -2}" # in older you could add spaces between OR
"${line::${#line}-2}"
```

Comment: `"${line: : -2}"` wouldn't work in older versions either. `${line:0:${#line}-2}` would and also work in `ksh93` (where that `${var:offset:length}` syntax comes from) and recent versions of `zsh`. See also `$line[1,-3]` in `zsh`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `grep` and look-ahead option (PCRE):

```
grep -Po '.*(?=..$)'
```